# How can i improve my post

Tags: discussion, support

I asked question on CS stack exchange , [How to solve following problem using segment trees?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116494/how-to-solve-following-problem-using-segment-trees) .I really want to improve thus i want to know how can i improve my post .

1.I copied question statement directly from website .I think explanation of question on that website was easiest and thus i copied the statement (but i have given the credits.)

2.I told my Approach.

My question is on hold and it's unlikely i will get answer .I want to know my mistakes in post.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start by editing your question based on the comments you have already received.  You already made a number of changes to improve your question based on feedback received, so I can understand why you might be discouraged or tired, but I want to give you some encouragement -- there is only a finite number of things you will need to address, and I believe you can do it.

I left you comments on how to improve your question.  Here is what I previously wrote:

> Now the problem is clear, but you copied from another source word-for-word without indicating what was copied.  We ask that you indicate which material is quoted or copied from another source by using the `>` blockquote environment -- see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing and https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for guidance.

You say "I have given the credits", but as I explain in the comment above, you have not followed our guidelines for how to give credit.

I also wrote:

> Also, what is your question, specifically?  If you didn't understand what they wrote and you're asking us to explain it to you, I worry that if someone else tries to explain it you might not understand that either.  It would help to ask a specific question about some specific aspect of it, and tell us what you did and didn't understand about that solution to help us give you an answer that will be useful to you.

This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a single, specific question in your post about your problem (it's not enough to just show the statement of the problem).

Neither of these comments have been addressed yet.

I don't know whether it's likely whether you will get an answer; I imagine that might depend on how you address the feedback you have received.  Don't assume that if you make these changes you are unlikely to receive an answer; I think it is entirely possible that if you improve the question, it will attract a good answer from someone who knows the subject.

Also, don't assume that "on hold" is permanent.  "On hold" is intended as a temporary status, to give you a chance to improve the question.  We want to make sure that the question is clear before inviting people to answer the question, and we want to save people from taking the time to write an answer that might be later invalidated if the question they answered wasn't the one you wanted them to answer.  Once the question is clear, the "on hold" status can be removed.

Comment: 1.I do not get how to reference , in the https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing it is told to add the link and i have added the link !  2.My question is to explain how to solve it using segment trees . 3. I think i have put considerable amount of effort and i am really tired so i cannot make more changes .One more think if any body gives answer to my question i will never down vote it (I will up vote for effort) .

Comment: I have made few more changes .Please check

Answer (score 2):

> But I do not get their approach.

This is not a valid question, so we don't know how to answer. I recommend you to mention explicitly where you don't understand.

Comment: I do not got how what is stored in segment tree (like least number in the given range) and how the update is done in O(logn) in this case .Basically if some one take an example input and tells up to to iterations what is happening i think i will get the idea of solution .

Comment: Don't explain what your question is here; edit your question to clearly state a specific question.